# Can a worker leave a territory controlled by an enemy mech?

Tags: scythe

I have already unlocked the +1 movement mech upgrade. I take one of my workers inside my mech, I use one of my movements for move this mech with the worker inside to a place where already are an enemy mech. I know my mech cant move more, cant use this +1 movement upgrade, need stay there and resolve the fight. But the question is, I have still one more movement for whatever other of my units before resolve that, so can I (with this other second movement) move this worker that was "inside my mech" out from this spot to other spot?

Answer (score 10):

No. The worker cannot leave a territory controlled by an enemy Mech. [The rulebook](https://app.box.com/s/rj3jrw0rab2uiz02up89kbant5g8ew1p/file/49368403634) says:

> If your character or mech move into a territory
> controlled by an opponent’s character and/or mechs,
> its movement ends (even if you have a mech ability
> that would allow it to move further). The opponent
> still temporarily controls that territory. After you’ve
> completed all Move actions, if any of your mechs or
> your character share a territory with an opponent’s
> character or mechs, combat happens (see Combat
> section, pages 22-23).

> Your workers cannot move by themselves into or out
> of territories controlled by opponent characters and/
> or mechs.